# grails: Unknown tag (oauth:connect)

Tags: grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, scribe

my gsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
</head>
<body>
    <oauth:connect provider="twitter">Connect to Twitter</oauth:connect>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run application
I jut get plain text : Connect to Twitter 
Don't get any button or link
and sts says:

```
Unknown tag (oauth:connect).
```

I have added following things in BuildConfig.groovy

```
  plugins {
    compile ':oauth:2.1.0'
    runtime ':oauth:2.1.0'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenRepo "http://repo.desirableobjects.co.uk/"
  }
```

And added following lines in Config.groovy

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.TwitterApi
oauth {
providers {
    twitter {
        api = TwitterApi
        key = 'my key is here'
        secret = 'my secret key is here'
        successUri = '/success.gsp'
        failureUri = '/fail.gsp'
    }
}
debug = true
}
```

My import is showing error though.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have edited the question and added some more info. let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: use `compile ":oauth:2.1.0"`. Remove rumtime and mavenRepo. In my priject I am just using 'compile ":oauth:2.1.0"'. Whats your grails version.

Comment: ok, thanks for quick response, my grails version is 2.3.0, again in my Config.groovy, my import is also giving compilation error, this is the error: Groovy:unable to resolve class org.scribe.builder.api.TwitterApi

Comment: In which port your application run. Is your oauth connect tah works now?

Comment: its running on 8080, tried what you said, its not working, are there any command i have to run other than clean, compile and run-app? after editing the BuildConfig?

Comment: Do you have any good tutorials which you had followed?

Comment: Tutorials: http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/grails-2-2-0-integration-with-twitter-using-grails-oauth-plugin/ and http://aiten.github.io/grails-oauth-scribe/

Comment: Have you try using grails refresh-depencies command as seen here http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/2/grails/installing-a-grails-plugin