# oauth facebook with grails accessing token

Tags: grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, scribe

Its a grails project,
Facebook authentication is successful via oauth, 
Now when it comes back to my controller, I want to get emailID of the logged in user, 
Searched a lot, but did not find proper documentation,
I am using scribe and have following code in Config.groory

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi

oauth {
providers {
    facebook {
        api = FacebookApi
        key = 'xxxx'
        secret = 'yyyy'
        callback = "http://my-domain-name-here:8080/TestOAuth2/dashBoard/facebooklogin"
        successUri = "http://my-domain-name-here:8080/TestOAuth2/dashBoard/success"
    }
}
}
```

Any help much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using grails oauth plugin? What is your request url? Whar are you getting from facebook?

Comment: I have edited the question and added some more info, I am not sure what is being received from facebook, but I am already logged in from browser so I assume authentication is successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..,.

**Config:**

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
...
oauth {
  providers {
    facebook {
      api = FacebookApi

      key = 'XXX'
      secret = 'YYY'

      scope = 'email,read_stream,publish_actions,user_birthday,publish_stream'

      callback = "http://localhost:8080/appName/oauth/facebook/callback"   //callback to oauth controller of oauth plugin

      successUri = "http://localhost:8080/appName/myController/facebookSuccess"
      failureUri = "http://localhost:8080/appName/myController/facebookFailure"
    }
  }
}
```

**MyController:**

```
def facebookSuccess() {
    Token facebookAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('facebook')]
    def facebookResource = oauthService.getFacebookResource(facebookAccessToken, "https://graph.facebook.com/me")
    def facebookResponse = JSON.parse(facebookResource?.getBody())

    log.info "Email = ${facebookResponse.email}"
    ...
}
```

You can get working example from my git repo. [Grails Oauth Plugin Demo](https://github.com/manishkbharti/grailsOauthPluginDemo).

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing. tried this. but getting NPE at.<br/>   def facebookResource = oauthService.getFacebookResource(facebookAccessToken, "https://graph.facebook.com/me") <br/> and i checked facebookAccessToken is null.

Comment: sure. its <oauth:connect provider="facebook" id="facebook-connect-link">Login using Facebook</oauth:connect>

Comment: In your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852258/grails-unknown-tag-oauthconnect question you have mentioned you are using grails 2.3.0. Right.

Comment: Let me test it on grails 2.3.0. I am currently using grials 2.2.0.

Comment: ok sure, you have been such a helpful through out the day.. :) thanks a lot.

Comment: I am able to get the email. I follow same steps as described. Have a look to this repo https://github.com/manishkbharti/grailsOauthPluginDemo

Answer (score 0):

**Email** is *not* part of a Facebook [public_profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile). The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) on the email field. You can do this by **adding a scope** to the oauth provider.

**config.groovy**

```
oauth {
   providers {
      facebook { 
          api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
          scope = 'email'
          ...
          ...
      } 
   }
}
```

As an example of how to return `email` and `various public_profile fields` please see below. 
*Take Note of:* `getFacebookResource` params e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,verified,age_range,email"`

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.scribe.model.Token
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth.OAuthToken

class SpringSecurityOAuthController {

   def oauthService

   def onSuccess = {
      // Validate the 'provider' URL. Any errors here are either misconfiguration
      // or web crawlers (or malicious users).
      if (!params.provider) {
        renderError 400, "The Spring Security OAuth callback URL must include the 'provider' URL parameter."
        return
      }

      def sessionKey = oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken(params.provider)
      if (!session[sessionKey]) {
          renderError 500, "No OAuth token in the session for provider '${params.provider}'!"
          return
      }

      // Create the relevant authentication token and attempt to log in.
      OAuthToken oAuthToken = createAuthToken(params.provider, session[sessionKey])

      Token facebookAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('facebook')]

      def facebookResource = oauthService.getFacebookResource(facebookAccessToken ,    "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,verified,age_range,email")

      def facebookResponse = JSON.parse(facebookResource?.getBody())

      println facebookResponse

      ...
      ...
    }
}
```

[public_profile (Default)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile)

A person's public profile refers to the following properties on the user object by default:

- id cover
- name
- first_name
- last_name
- age_range
- link
- gender
- locale
- picture
- timezone
- updated_time
- verified