# Get email address using grails social plugin from Social sites

Tags: grails, oauth, grails-plugin

I am using Grails social authentication plugin.So I need to get user email address from facebook , twitter , linkedin. Now i am able to get OauthToken ,but in response i am getting **Social ID:87875576 emailId:87875576 name:87875576** in case of Facebook, linkedin.

Can anyone please help me.How to get email address.

thanks

Comment: not sure about the plugin actually, but if it's based on Spring Social then take a look at this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#retrieving-a-user-s-profile-data (similar for others)

Comment: I haven't used `grails social plugin`, but I have used `grails Oauth Plugin` and my suggestion is:- set correct scope and request to the correct URL with valid oauth toket and they send back the user info you want. Grails osuth plugin demo @http://grailsoauthplugindemo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Yes i tried to set scope in Config.groovy but still not get.

Comment: Please see here for accessing email for facebook: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41906102/1486634